# fetching data in while loop in list tag

Tags: php, css

```
while($recor1=mysql_fetch_assoc($res1))
                            {

                              ?>
                                <ul>
                                <li  class="col-md-3 col-sm-3"><a href="#"><div class="dest-list"><?php echo $recor1['sub_destination']; ?></div></a> </li>

                                </ul>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                              <?php 
                            }
```

it displays the result horizontally i want it vertically please give me soluation

Comment: what are you using for col-md-3 for li ?

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of things wrong with your code, why are you adding a new list for every item with only one list item, that makes no sense. Also do not add block elements inside inline elements (div inside a). Also if you what the list items under each other then why add the col-... class?

```
<ul>
<?php while($recor1=mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) {?>
    <li class="">
        <a href="#">
            <?php echo $recor1['sub_destination']; ?>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
</ul>
```

this gives you the right html structure, and you can then style it as you see fit

Comment: thank maybe you could accept my answer in case someone else stumbles upon this question...

Answer (score 0):

if you dont want to display a list horizontally remove col-sm-3 class of your li, which changes your code like below

```
  while($recor1=mysql_fetch_assoc($res1)) { ?>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
   <ul>
    <li >
        <a href="#">
            <div class="dest-list">
                 <?php echo $recor1['sub_destination']; ?>
            </div>
        </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
 </div>

 <div class="clearfix"></div>

 <?php 
 }
```

take a look at this  [example](http://codepen.io/raghucse2010/pen/JGmojG)